# Django Cache solution for max_user_connections

Tags: database, django, caching

My website has stated to get the following error: OperationalError: (1203, "User xxxxx already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections")

From what I understand this is because there are too many requests to the database at one time and the database cannot cope. Ideally I need to setup caching for the database access and know this is pretty easy to do with Django, but the question is, which cache solution is best.

My hosting is on the MediaTemple gridserver platform if that helps. As far as I am aware I can use any or the solutions that Django provides: http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter14/

Is there a good way to figure out what the best option should be? I don't generally have much traffic, but sometimes there can be a spike and the content is pretty much static, except for the odd blog post, that doesn't have to be to 'fresh'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read a cache solution comparison [here](http://codysoyland.com/2010/jan/17/evaluating-django-caching-options/).I guess [django-staticgenerator](http://superjared.com/projects/static-generator/) would be what are looking for.
And you can take a  look at [Johny-cache](http://django.jmoiron.net/blog/johnny-cache/)

Comment: Thanks, that is a really useful article. You are probably right about django-staticgenerator being what I am looking for. Looking over it's documentation it would seem that it will be easy to install also.